# JQuery dry code for uncheck and check checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have a jquery code for check/uncheck and enable/disable checkboxes, but the code is not very well written, because i have to copy and paste the same code to differentiate the checkboxes at different div container, is there any way to make the code can be called with one function?, i'm still new in jquery so i'm blind with keeping the jquery code very well/efficient written or dry, here's the jquery code:

```
//for container sales toggle show/hide
$('#show_hide_sales').click(function (e) {
  $('#show_hide_sales').closest("#sales").find(".row:gt(0)").slideToggle("fast");
  var val = $(this).text() == "-" ? "+" : "-";
  $(this).hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('#sales').each(function(){//loop through each container,must have different name of classes or id
$('#sales').find ($('#row_sales:first')).each(function(){ // get first row (header), need different row id name for this one line
    $('#title_sales').click(function(){ //if text header clicked,must have different name of classes or id
      var cur = $(this).closest('.row').closest('#sales').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(1)').find('input'); //get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
           $(cur).closest('.row').find('div:gt(1) input').prop("disabled", false);
           $("input[id^='auth2']").each(function(){
                $(this).prop("checked",true);
           });
      }else{
        $(cur).closest('.row').find('div:gt(1) input').prop("disabled", true);
        $("input[id^='auth2']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
    }
    });
    $('#sales_add').click(function(){//must have different name of classes or id for add, edit, and delete
      var cur = $(this).closest('#sales').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(2)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='addAuth2']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='addAuth2']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    $('#sales_edit').click(function(){
      var cur = $(this).closest('#sales').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(3)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='editAuth2']").each(function(){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='editAuth2']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    $('#sales_del').click(function(){
      var cur = $(this).closest('#sales').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(4)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='delAuth2']").each(function(){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='delAuth2']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    });
  });

//for container inventory toggle show/hide
$('#show_hide_inventory').click(function (e) {
  $('#show_hide_inventory').closest("#inventory").find(".row:gt(0)").slideToggle("fast");
  var val = $(this).text() == "-" ? "+" : "-";
  $(this).hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('#inventory').each(function(){//loop through each container,must have different name of classes or id
$('#inventory').find ($('#row_inventory:first')).each(function(){ // get first row (header), need different row id name for this one line
    $('#title_inventory').click(function(){ //if text header clicked,must have different name of classes or id
      var cur = $(this).closest('.row').closest('#inventory').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(1)').find('input'); //get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
           $(cur).closest('.row').find('div:gt(1) input').prop("disabled", false);
           $("input[id^='auth3']").each(function(){
                $(this).prop("checked",true);
           });
      }else{
        $(cur).closest('.row').find('div:gt(1) input').prop("disabled", true);
        $("input[id^='auth3']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
    }
    });
    $('#inventory_add').click(function(){//must have different name of classes or id for add, edit, and delete
      var cur = $(this).closest('#inventory').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(2)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='addAuth3']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='addAuth3']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    $('#inventory_edit').click(function(){
      var cur = $(this).closest('#inventory').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(3)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='editAuth3']").each(function(){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='editAuth3']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    $('#inventory_del').click(function(){
      var cur = $(this).closest('#inventory').find(".row:gt(0)").find('div:eq(4)').find('input');//get first column checkboxes
      if(!$(cur).prop('checked')){
        $("input[id^='delAuth3']").each(function(){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
      }else{
        $("input[id^='delAuth3']").each(function(){
               $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
      }
    });
    });
  });
```

here's the example of the running program [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t758jod6)

Comment: Not sure I understood your question, but anyway... You can simply create a small function that receives as a parameter the ID of a checkbox and the action you want to do on it, and invoke that function with the right parameters whenever you need.

Comment: show a full working code in fiddle or on the code-runner, then we can probably help you out.

Comment: @Iceman i've edited my question, cekidot

Comment: @Wallflower can i edit only the js, is it fine to adjust the html at one point as well?

Comment: @Wallflower have a look at my answer below. I've reduced the JS to about 25-30% of the original. I think beyond wud be pushing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've reduced your code from about **123 lines** to **about 25 lines**. Replace your Javascript with below code. Exactly same functionalities (but incase I missed something, pls comment below!!)

```
$(function() {
  function retObj(name){ return {name: name, data:[false],options: [['add',false], ['edit',false], ['del',false]]};}
  var containers = [ retObj('sales'), retObj('inventory')];
  containers.forEach(function(container) {
    $("#show_hide_"+ container.name).click(function(){
      $('#'+container.name).children("div:not(#row_"+container.name+")").slideToggle('fast');
      this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === '+')? '-': '+';
    });   
    $("#title_" + container.name).click(function(){
      container.data[0] = !container.data[0];
      $('#'+container.name).find("[id^=auth]").each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", container.data[0]);
        });
    });
    var options = container.options;
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      $("#"+container.name+"_" + option[0]).click(function() {
        option[1] = !option[1];
        $('#'+container.name).find("[id^=" + option[0] + "Auth]").each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", option[1]);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

The UPDATED FIDDLE I've just replaced the Javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/t758jod6/1/

---

**A WORKING SNIPPET to run here itself:**

```js
$(function() {
  function retObj(name){ return {name: name, data:[false],options: [['add',false], ['edit',false], ['del',false]]};}
  var containers = [ retObj('sales'), retObj('inventory')];
  containers.forEach(function(container) {
    $("#show_hide_"+ container.name).click(function(){
      $('#'+container.name).children("div:not(#row_"+container.name+")").slideToggle('fast');
      this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === '+')? '-': '+';
    });   
    $("#title_" + container.name).click(function(){
      container.data[0] = !container.data[0];
      $('#'+container.name).find("[id^=auth]").each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", container.data[0]);
        });
    });
    var options = container.options;
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      $("#"+container.name+"_" + option[0]).click(function() {
        option[1] = !option[1];
        $('#'+container.name).find("[id^=" + option[0] + "Auth]").each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", option[1]);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="sales">
  <div class="row" id="row_sales">
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <p id="show_hide_sales">-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="title_sales">Sales</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="sales_add">ToogleAdd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="sales_edit">ToogleEdit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="sales_del">ToogleDel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth200" value="auth200" id="auth200">New Member Invoice</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth200" value="addAuth200" id="addAuth200">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth200" value="editAuth200" id="editAuth200">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth200" value="delAuth200" id="delAuth200">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth201" value="auth201" id="auth201">Member Invoice Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth201" value="addAuth201" id="addAuth201">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth201" value="editAuth201" id="editAuth201">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth201" value="delAuth201" id="delAuth201">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth202" value="auth202" id="auth202">New Stockiest Invoice</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth202" value="addAuth202" id="addAuth202">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth202" value="editAuth202" id="editAuth202">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth202" value="delAuth202" id="delAuth202">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth203" value="auth203" id="auth203">Stockiest Invoice Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth203" value="addAuth203" id="addAuth203">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth203" value="editAuth203" id="editAuth203">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth203" value="delAuth203" id="delAuth203">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth204" value="auth204" id="auth204">New Shipment</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth204" value="addAuth204" id="addAuth204">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth204" value="editAuth204" id="editAuth204">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth204" value="delAuth204" id="delAuth204">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth205" value="auth205" id="auth205">Shipment Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth205" value="addAuth205" id="addAuth205">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth205" value="editAuth205" id="editAuth205">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth205" value="delAuth205" id="delAuth205">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth206" value="auth206" id="auth206">Invoice & Shipment Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth206" value="addAuth206" id="addAuth206">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth206" value="editAuth206" id="editAuth206">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth206" value="delAuth206" id="delAuth206">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth207" value="auth207" id="auth207">Daily Sales Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth207" value="addAuth207" id="addAuth207">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth207" value="editAuth207" id="editAuth207">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth207" value="delAuth207" id="delAuth207">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth208" value="auth208" id="auth208">PV Group Report (Gen)</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth208" value="addAuth208" id="addAuth208">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth208" value="editAuth208" id="editAuth208">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth208" value="delAuth208" id="delAuth208">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth209" value="auth209" id="auth209">PV Group Report (Tree)</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth209" value="addAuth209" id="addAuth209">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth209" value="editAuth209" id="editAuth209">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth209" value="delAuth209" id="delAuth209">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth210" value="auth210" id="auth210">Preproses PV Group (Gen)</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth210" value="addAuth210" id="addAuth210">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth210" value="editAuth210" id="editAuth210">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth210" value="delAuth210" id="delAuth210">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth211" value="auth211" id="auth211">Product Sales Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth211" value="addAuth211" id="addAuth211">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth211" value="editAuth211" id="editAuth211">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth211" value="delAuth211" id="delAuth211">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth212" value="auth212" id="auth212">Monthly Sales Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth212" value="addAuth212" id="addAuth212">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth212" value="editAuth212" id="editAuth212">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth212" value="delAuth212" id="delAuth212">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="inventory">
  <div class="row" id="row_inventory">
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <p id="show_hide_inventory">-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="title_inventory">Inventory</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="inventory_add">ToogleAdd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="inventory_edit">ToogleEdit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#4ABDAC;">
      <P id="inventory_del">ToogleDel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth300" value="auth300" id="auth300">Inventory Trx Entry</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth300" value="addAuth300" id="addAuth300">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth300" value="editAuth300" id="editAuth300">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth300" value="delAuth300" id="delAuth300">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth301" value="auth301" id="auth301">Product Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth301" value="addAuth301" id="addAuth301">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth301" value="editAuth301" id="editAuth301">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth301" value="delAuth301" id="delAuth301">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth302" value="auth302" id="auth302">Product Package Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth302" value="addAuth302" id="addAuth302">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth302" value="editAuth302" id="editAuth302">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth302" value="delAuth302" id="delAuth302">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth303" value="auth303" id="auth303">Product Selling Price</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth303" value="addAuth303" id="addAuth303">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth303" value="editAuth303" id="editAuth303">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth303" value="delAuth303" id="delAuth303">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth304" value="auth304" id="auth304">Pricing Code</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth304" value="addAuth304" id="addAuth304">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth304" value="editAuth304" id="editAuth304">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth304" value="delAuth304" id="delAuth304">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth305" value="auth305" id="auth305">Trx Type Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth305" value="addAuth305" id="addAuth305">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth305" value="editAuth305" id="editAuth305">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth305" value="delAuth305" id="delAuth305">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth306" value="auth306" id="auth306">WareHouse Maintenance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth306" value="addAuth306" id="addAuth306">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth306" value="editAuth306" id="editAuth306">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth306" value="delAuth306" id="delAuth306">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth307" value="auth307" id="auth307">Inventory Trx Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth307" value="addAuth307" id="addAuth307">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth307" value="editAuth307" id="editAuth307">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth307" value="delAuth307" id="delAuth307">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth308" value="auth308" id="auth308">Inventory Balance Stock Report</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth308" value="addAuth308" id="addAuth308">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth308" value="editAuth308" id="editAuth308">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth308" value="delAuth308" id="delAuth308">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth309" value="auth309" id="auth309">Product Listing</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth309" value="addAuth309" id="addAuth309">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth309" value="editAuth309" id="editAuth309">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth309" value="delAuth309" id="delAuth309">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="auth310" value="auth310" id="auth310">History Stock Balance</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="addAuth310" value="addAuth310" id="addAuth310">Add</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="editAuth310" value="editAuth310" id="editAuth310">Edit</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delAuth310" value="delAuth310" id="delAuth310">Delete</input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

*I'm assuming that your HTML cannot be edited (or you don't want to). If you can, then we probably can tweak the HTML, and sweeten (or dry) the JS code a bit more.*

Comment: the html is fine as it is i guess, ty for ur answer

Comment: @Wallflower Cheers...glad i cud be of help .